# What value does the return value take if something is not in a map?

Tags: go

Ok so according to this:

[How to check if a map contains a key in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050391/how-to-check-if-a-map-contains-a-key-in-go)

```
if val, ok := m["foo"]; ok {
    //do something here
}
```

that's fine, but how come we can't do this:

```
val, ok := m["foo"]

if val == nil {   // cannot compare val to nil

}
```

I get a compilation error saying I can't compare val to nil, but then what value does val have? What can I compare it to, to determine if it exists or not?

the type of m is like:

```
type m map[string]struct{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)
>
> For a of map type M: if the map is nil or does not contain such an
>   entry, a[x] is the zero value for the element type of M.
>
> [The zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
>   or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a
>   composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is
>   provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
>   of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type:
>   false for booleans, 0 for numeric types, "" for strings, and nil for
>   pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)
>
> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and
>   maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated. They consist
>   of the type of the literal followed by a brace-bound list of elements.
>   Each element may optionally be preceded by a corresponding key.  For
>   struct literals the following rules apply:
>
> A literal may omit the element list; such a literal evaluates to the
>   zero value for its type.

For your example, type `struct{}`, omit the element list from the composite literal, `struct{}{}`, for the zero value.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := map[string]struct{}{}
    val, ok := m["foo"]
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", val, val)
    if val == struct{}{} {
        fmt.Println("==", val, ok)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/44D_ZfFDA77

Output:

```
struct {} {}
== {} false
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)
>
> A variable declaration creates one or more variables, binds
>   corresponding identifiers to them, and gives each a type and an
>   initial value.
>
> If a list of expressions is given, the variables are initialized with
>   the expressions following the rules for assignments. Otherwise, each
>   variable is initialized to its zero value.
>
> If a type is present, each variable is given that type. Otherwise,
>   each variable is given the type of the corresponding initialization
>   value in the assignment.

In your example, you could declare a variable of type `struct{}` with no initial value, which would be initialized to the zero value for the `struct{}` type.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := map[string]struct{}{}
    val, ok := m["foo"]
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", val, val)
    var zeroValue struct{}
    if val == zeroValue {
        fmt.Println("==", val, ok)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/_XcSCEeEKJV

Output:

```
struct {} {}
== {} false
```

Comment: according to this, the zero-value of a struct should be nil? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625794/structs-zero-value-in-golang

Comment: @MrCholo: The zero value of a `struct` is the composite of the zero values of its fields.

Comment: Ah shizz, that doesn't sound like `nil` to me, hence why I was getting what I was getting in the OP

Comment: I wonder what the point of `composite of the zero values of its fields` is, why not just nil? Because NPEs are bad?

Answer (score -1):

You can most certainly do what you did above. Comparing to nil depends on the type of value you have in map. If its `interface{}` you can compare it to nil:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{}

val, _ := m["foo"]

if val == nil {
    fmt.Println("no index")
}
```