# Passing closure as function's argument

Tags: go, closures

From this example: https://gobyexample.com/closures
If we change:

```
    fmt.Println(nextInt())
    fmt.Println(nextInt())
    fmt.Println(nextInt())
```

to

```
    fmt.Println(intSeq())
    fmt.Println(intSeq())
    fmt.Println(intSeq())
```

`go run` will fail with error: `./prog.go:32:5: Println arg intSeq() is a func value, not called`

But from this example: https://gobyexample.com/recursion

```
    fmt.Println(fact(7))
```

We can call `fact(7)` function as `fmt.Println`'s argument. Why we have difference?

Comment: `go run` doesn't fail. But `go vet` let's you know that you're not calling the function returned by intSeq: https://play.golang.org/p/yKuLRWxWXtQ.

Comment: @Peter. So we have to call the inner anon function?

Comment: @TuyenPham no, if it compiles it's a valid go program, regardless of whether or not it actually produces the result you intended. https://golang.org/cmd/vet/ *"Vet examines Go source code and **reports suspicious constructs**, such as Printf calls whose arguments do not align with the format string. Vet uses heuristics that **do not guarantee all reports are genuine problems**, but it can find errors not caught by the compilers."*

Comment: Please include complete code necessary to understand the question _in the question_.

Answer (score 1):

To reckon.
When you run Golang playground or any Test in your code, `go vet` run first and if it return with error the actual go code doesn't run.

If you `go build` , or `go run` (tested with 1.12.5) the code run perfectly, printing the function pointer address.

If you copy your code to the tutorial site, here https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1 for example. the code work as you expected.

Comment: Should `fmt.Println(nextInt())` and `fmt.Println(intSeq())` produce the same result? I expected somehow `go` also call the returned anon function.